# dictionary-based compression algorithm: in assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86

dictionary-based compression algorithm:

dictionary-based compression algorithm:
1. analyze the file and make a list of all words in text without taking into account the
uppercase and multiple appearances (builds the set of words that make up the
text). Each word is assigned an ASCII character, so is constructing a dictionary.
2. In the text file will replace the words with their correspondent (ASCII character) of
Dictionary. It will save new disk file and another file that contains dictionary.

The problem is that my code does not work. When i open de .exe file. the message "path to the folder" appears, and when i write the folder name and push enter, it stops working.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;include libraries, and declare what functions we want to import
includelib msvcrt.lib
extern printf: proc
extern fscanf: proc
extern fopen: proc
extern fprintf: proc
extern fclose: proc
extern printf: proc
extern scanf: proc
extern exit: proc
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

public start
;declare the start symbol as public - from there the execution begins
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;sections of the program, data or code
.data
mesaj1 db "path to the folder:", 0
format db "%s", 0
format_cit db "%s", 0
format_dic db "%d", 0
filename db "text.txt", 0
mode_r db "r", 0
wfilename db "text2.txt", 0
mode_w db "w", 0
dfilename db "dic.txt", 0
n db 10 dup(0)
DICTIONAR struct
    cuv db 10 dup(0)
    var dd 0
DICTIONAR ends
var DICTIONAR 10 dup({}) ;Initialize an array of struct DICTIONAR where it will save vocabulary
nr db 0
rez db 10 dup(0)
index db 0
virgula db ",", 0
.code
start:
    ;enter the path to the file
    push offset mesaj1
    call printf
    add esp, 4
    push offset filename
    push offset format
    call scanf
    add esp, 8

    ;call fopen
    push offset mode_r
    push offset filename
    call fopen
    add esp, 8
    mov ebx, eax ;salvam pointer-ul la fisier


    ;call fopen
    push offset mode_w
    push offset wfilename
    call fopen
    add esp,8
    mov ebx, eax
    ;-
    mov eax, esi;  move the pointer on the reading file
    lea edi, var[0].cuv

    ;put on the stack parameters for fread
    readig_loop:
    push offset n ;
    push offset format_cit ;
    push ebx ;stream
    call fscanf
    ;-
    mov edx,edi
    ;check if it has reached the end of the file
    add eax,1
    test eax, eax
    jz inchidere_fisier
    xor eax, eax ;facem eax sa fie 0
    ;-

    ;check if the vord exists in the dictionary
    xor ecx,ecx ;curatam ecx 
    mov cl,nr   ;put in cl the number of words from the dictionary
    add cl,1    ;start count from 1
    mov edi,edx
    lea edx,var[0].cuv

    add:
    lea esi,n
    dec edx
    xor ebp,ebp
    dec ebp

    compare:
    inc edx
    inc ebp
    lodsb
    cmp [edx],al
    jne different
    cmp al,0
    je egal
    jne compare

    different:
    sub edx,ebp
    add edx,12
    loop add
    mov edx,edi
    lea esi,n
    xor ebp,ebp

    copy:
    inc ebp
    mov al,[esi]
    cmp al,0
    je done
    mov[edx],al
    inc esi
    inc edx
    jmp copy

    done:
    sub edx,ebp
    inc edx
    add [nr],1
    add edx,10
    mov cl,nr
    add cl,48
    mov [edx],cl
    add edx,2
    mov edi,edx
    lea eax,rez
    add al,index
    mov [eax],cl
    add [index],1
    jmp bucla_citire

    eqals:
    sub edx,ebp
    mov ebp,edx
    add edx,10
    lea eax,rez
    add al,index
    mov cl,[edx]
    mov [eax],cl
    add [index],1
    mov edi,edx
    jmp reading_loop

    close_the_folder:
    ;call fclose
    push ebx ;stream
    call fclose
    push offset mode_w
    push offset wfilename
    call fopen

    write_fis:
    push offset rez
    push offset format
    push eax
    call fprintf
    push offset rez
    push offset format
    call printf

    ;write in the dictionery file
    push offset mode_w
    push offset dfilename
    call fopen
    mov esp,eax
    xor ebx,ebx
    mov bl,nr
    lea ebp,var[0].cuv

    write_dic:
    push ebp
    push offset format
    push esp
    call fprintf
    add ebp,10
    xor ecx,ecx
    mov cl,[esi]
    push cx
    push offset format_dic
    push esp
    call fprintf
    add ebp,2
    push offset virgula
    push offset format
    push esp
    call fprintf
    dec bl
    cmp bl,0
    jne write_dic

;end
    push 0
    call exit
end start
```

Comment: The buffer you pass to `scanf` can only hold 8 characters and the null terminator. What input are you giving to the program? Maybe it's too long and `scanf` is overwritting other variables.

Comment: text.txt is the input, wright?

Comment: well, no, it depends on what you write when you are asked for the input file path :) But I guess the answer given by _user3144770_ points to other problem which is more serious.

Answer (score 2):

On both *fopen* calls you're saving EAX in the same register EBX. Then what's the point doing it the first time?

```
;call fopen
push offset mode_r
push offset filename
call fopen
add esp, 8
mov ebx, eax ;salvam pointer-ul la fisier


;call fopen
push offset mode_w
push offset wfilename
call fopen
add esp,8
mov ebx, eax
```

Basically you're reading from your output file.